# How to format this string to a date format?

Tags: php

There is a string posted from a web page form : `Jul 21 2015`. It represents a date but needs to be formatted. How to format it to be `2015-07-21` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)**:

```
$string = "Jul 21 2015";
$time = date("Y-m-j", strtotime($string));
```